# Set starting sequence values as max(id)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to change sequnce name in Oracle DB, but I can't use rename (no need to do epxlain why). I'm trying to drop it and create new one with different name. But I need to set sequence value as max(id)+1. I am trying these commands:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test START WITH
  ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM test_table
  )
INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 100000 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NOCACHE;



CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test START WITH
  to_number( SELECT MAX(id) FROM test_table
)
INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 100000 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NOCACHE;
```

For both cases I am getting 
    SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: `9223372036854775807` seems a very specific maxvalue. Also `nocache` is generally not a good idea - are you sure you want to disable caching? It will hurt performance if the sequence is frequently used.

Comment: this is something it's not up to me, I must leave it as it is.

Comment: Regarding `nocache`, I often see it copied & pasted from some other script by people who don't know what it does, therefore I would want to double-check that it really is needed. For the other values, it is clearer to specify only non-default values, e.g. `create sequence seq_test start with xxx minvalue yyy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE
   seq_id   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX (id) INTO seq_id FROM test_table;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test 
                               START WITH '
      || seq_id
      || ' INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 100000 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 NOCACHE';
END;
/
```